# Elasticsearch: undefined method `params_encoder' for {"timeout"=>300, :proxy=>nil}:Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have install Elasticsearch inside docker.
I got response of elastic search like this-

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200
{
    "name" : "NXgYHOl",
    "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
    "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
    "version" : {
        "number" : "6.6.0",
        "build_flavor" : "default",
        "build_type" : "tar",
        "build_hash" : "a9861f4",
        "build_date" : "2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Then I configure it in a `rails` project.

Gemfile

```
  gem 'elasticsearch-model'
  gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
```

app/models

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
end
Movie.import(force: true)
```

config/initilizers/elasticsearch.rb

```
config = {
    host: "http://localhost:9200",
    transport_options: {
      request: { timeout: 5 }
    }
}

if File.exists?("config/elasticsearch.yml")
    config.merge!(YAML.load_file("config/elasticsearch.yml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys)
end

Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```

config/elasticsearch.yml

```
development: &default
    host: 'http://localhost:9200'
    transport_options:
      request:
        timeout: !!integer 300
test:
    <<: *default
production:
    host: 'http://localhost:9200'
  transport_options:
    request:
        timeout: !!integer 300
```

It gives an error:

> undefined method `params_encoder' for {"timeout"=>300, :proxy=>nil}:Hash

I don't understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `transport_options` is not an option according to the [official docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-transport/Elasticsearch/Transport/Client) of the ruby gem.

It does however mention a `request_timeout` option, which should work.
So change your `config/elasticsearch.yml` file to the following:

```
development: &default
    host: 'http://localhost:9200'
    request_timeout: !!integer 300
test:
    <<: *default
production:
    host: 'http://localhost:9200'
    request_timeout: !!integer 300
```